# Real running time calculation of matrix multiplication

Tags: performance

I would like to calculate approximately the running time of a matrix multiplication problem. Below are my assumptions:

- No parallel programming
- A 2 Ghz CPU
- A square matrix of size n
- An O(n^3) algorithm

For example suppose that n = 1000. So, how much time (approximately) should I expect taking the square of this matrix will take on the above assumptions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really terribly depends on the algorithm and the CPU. Even without parallelization, there's a lot of freedom in how the same steps would be represented on a CPU, and differences (in clock cycles needed for various operations) between different CPU's of the same family, too. Don't forget, either, that modern CPUs add some parallelization of instructions on their own. Optimization done by the compiler will make a difference in reordering memory order and branches and will likely convert instructions to vectorized ones even if you didn't specify that. Depending on further factors it may make a difference, too, whether your matrices are in a fixed location in memory or if you are accessing them by a pointer, and whether they are allocated with fixed size or each row / column dynamically. Don't forget about memory caching, page invalidations, and operation system scheduling, as I did in previous versions of my answer.

If this is for your own **rough** estimate or for a "typical" case, you won't do much wrong by just writing the program, running it **in your specific conditions** (as discussed above) in many repetitions for n = 1000, and calculating the average.

If you want a lot of hard work for a worse result, you can actually do what you probably meant to do in your original question yourself:

1. see what instructions your *specific* compiler produces for your *specific* algorithm under your *specific* conditions and with *specific* optimization settings (like [here](https://godbolt.org/g/C7EG3E))
2. pick your *specific* processor and find its [latency table for every instruction that's there](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf),
3. add them up per iteration and multiply by 1000^3,
4. divide by the clock frequency.

Seriously, it's not worth the effort, a benchmark is faster, clearer, and more precise anyway (as this does not account for what happens in the branch predictor and hyperthreading and memory caching and other architectural details). If you want an exercise I'll leave that to you.

Comment: We should probably look at the throughput though, matrix multiplication doesn't really have huge dependency chains unless you implement it naively .. then again, that shows just how much difference the implementation details make

Comment: I agree with you @The Vee. This also shows the importance of experimental running time calculation. For the curious, the following are the results of square matrix multiplication with size n on my machine. n=1000, time=2.5 secs; n=2000, time=20 secs; n=3000, time=110 secs; n=4000, time=266 secs.